# nlrx/netlogo can't find the gis extension

Tags: r, netlogo

I was trying to run a sensitivity analysis using the `nlrx` r package. All the system requirements seem to be satisfied:

```bash
$ java -version
java version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)

$ javac -version
javac 16.0.1
```

However, when I reach running the experiment, I get the `gis` extension can't be found.

What can I do to make it work? Thank you.

```r
library(nlrx)

# Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME"="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_361")
# Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME"="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-16.0.1")
nl_path = "C:/Program Files/NetLogo 6.3.0"
nl_version = "6.3.0"
model_path = file.path(
  "C:/Users/derke001/Documents/My desktop/ABM/Article ABM/model/",
  "Netlogo_the latest/(V5.4) Netlogo Amsterdam - Mark/(V5.4) Netlogo Amsterdam - Mark/V(6.0) BehaviorSpace version.nlogo"
)
out_path = "C:/Users/derke001/Documents/My desktop/ABM/Article ABM/model/Netlogo_the_latest"

#create a nl object
model <- nl(
  nlversion = nl_version,
  nlpath = nl_path,
  modelpath = model_path,
  jvmmem = 1024
)

##experiment1 - electricity price
model@experiment <- experiment(
  expname = "elec-price",
  outpath = out_path,
  repetition = 1,
  tickmetrics = "true",
  idsetup = "setup-quick",
  idgo = "go",
  runtime = 10,
  metrics = c(
    db = "length filter [ i -> i = 2 ] overview-investments-owner",
    ins = "length filter [ i -> i = 3 ] overview-investments-owner",
    pv = "length filter [ i -> i = 4 ] overview-investments-owner",
    hp = "length filter [ i -> i = 5 ] overview-investments-owner",
    "r-seed"
  ),
  variables = list("electricity-price" = list(values=c(0.082, 0.232, 0.382))),
  constants = list(
    "dataset-residents" = "4. dataset residents/zuid-oost.csv",
    "gas-price" = 0.829,
    "owners-only?" = "true",
    "new-random-seed?" = "true",
    "min-building-size" = 3,
    "unc-energy-prices-mean" = 0.2,
    "owners-building-only?" = "false",
    "unc-stand.dev-consumat" = 0.05,
    "collective-dm?" = "true",
    "maximum-years" = 10
  )
)

eval_variables_constants(model)

model@simdesign = simdesign_ff(nl = model, nseeds = 20)

results = run_nl_all(model)
```

```r
> eval_variables_constants(model)
All defined variables and constants are valid!
> 
> model@simdesign = simdesign_ff(nl = model, nseeds = 20)
Creating full factorial simulation design
> results = run_nl_all(model)
Exception in thread "main" Can't find extension: gis at position 15 in 
    at org.nlogo.core.ErrorSource.signalError(ErrorSource.scala:11)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.ExtensionManager.importExtension(ExtensionManager.scala:180)
***
```

I have tried with different versions of java.

Answer (score 2):

NetLogo checks for extensions in certain paths based on the working direcetory it's started in.  A [full listing of those paths is here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/extensions.html#where-extensions-are-located).  Likely the issue is that the working directory for your nlrx session is not the same as the NetLogo application directory.  Here are some potential workarounds (apologies that I cannot test these at the moment):

1. Setting [the `netlogo.extensions.dir` Java system property](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Java-System-Properties-and-how-to-use-them) would be an easy way to get NetLogo looking in the right spot.  For Windows, given the paths you listed you want to point it to `C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.3.0\extensions\.bundled\`.  I don't know if nlrx provides a simple way to set Java properties for the NetLogo session or not.
2. Add a symbolic link to the NetLogo bundled extensions folder from your nlrx working directory.  It looks like you're using Windows, so while this solution may be possible I'm not sure how to do it off the top of my head.
3. In the NetLogo GUI, use [the Extension Manager](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/extension-manager.html) to install the updated GIS extension (v1.3.2 as of this writing).  This will place the extension in a user-specific folder not relative to the program installation, so it should be detected when running through nlrx as well.  This is a good solution in this particular case because the GIS extension was updated after NetLogo 6.3.0 was released, but it would not work in cases where a bundled extension wasn't updated.
4. Copy the GIS extension files into the same folder your model lives in.  Just browse to `NetLogo 6.3.0/extensions/.bundled/gis` and copy everything to your model's directory.  Really only the `*.jar` files are needed, but the rest won't hurt.  This is the least desireable solution because it could cause issues and confusion with NetLogo version updates, but it should definitely work.

I hope one of those helps.